# How to get a generic interface without knowing its specific type?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, interface

This is my problem (please bear with me here).

I have the following base class and interface

```
public abstract class Entity 
{
    public Entity()
    {
    }
}

public interface IRelatable<T> where T : Entity
{
    T RelatedEntity { get; set; }

    void RelateTo()
}
```

I have two classes that inherits from Entity:

```
public class E1 : Entity
{
    public E1
   {
   }
}


public class E2 : Entity, IRelatable<E1>
{
    public E2
    {
    }

    public E1 RelatedEntity { get; set; }

    public void RelateTo()
    {
        // To some code here ....
    }    
}
```

Now, I want to get the RelatedEntity of E2, something like this:

```
public void DoReflcetion(Entity ent)
{
   var ent2 = (ent as IRelatable<>).RelatedEntity;
}
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Thank you,
Omri

---

A. Thank you for your answer.
B. The problem is that I want to access RelatedEntity from a non-generic class like this:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public void DoSomething(IRelatable<> rel)
    {
        rel.RelateTo();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access RelatedEntity from a non-generic class, then create generic method

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public void DoSomething<T>(IRelatable<T> rel)
        where T : Entity
    {
        T relatedTo = rel.RelatedEntity;
        // ...        
    }
}
```

Type of T will be inferred from argument type:

```
SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass();
E2 e2 = new E2() { RelatedEntity = new E1() };
s.DoSomething(e2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
public class SomeClass<T> where T: Entity
{
    public void DoSomething(IRelatable<T> rel)
    {
        T relatedTo = rel.RelatedEntity;
        // ...
    }
}
```

Although I would recommend using a simpler model for representing relationships between entities.

Comment: A. Thank you for your answer. 
B. The problem is that I want to access RelatedEntity from a non-generic class like this:

`public class SomeClass
{
    public void DoSomething(IRelatable<> rel)
    {
        rel.RelateTo();
    }
}`